# Can dropout increases training data performance?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, training-data, loss-function, dropout

I am training a neural network with dropout. It happens that as I decrease dropout from 0.9 to 0.7, the loss (cross-validation error) also decreases for the training data data. I noticed also that accuracy increases as I reduce dropout parameter.

It seems odd to me. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Dropout is a regularization technique. You should use it only to reduce variance (validation performance vs training performance).It is not intended to reduce the bias, and you should not use it in this way. **it is very misleading.**

**Probably the reason for which you see this behavior is that you use a very high value for dropout.** 0.9 means you neutralize too many neurons. It makes sense that once you put there 0.7 instead, the network has higher neurons to use while learning on training set. So the performance will increase for lower values.

**You usually should see the training performance dropping a bit, while increasing the performance on the validation set (if you do not have one, at least on the test set). This is the desired behavior you are looking for, when using dropout.** The current behavior you get is because if the very high values for dropout.

**Start with 0.2 or 0.3** and compare the bias vs. variance in order to get a good value for dropout.

**My clear recommendation: don't use it to improve bias, but to reduce variance (error on validation set).**

In order to fit better on the training set I recommend :

1. find a better architecture (or change the number of neurons per
   layer)
2. try different optimizers
3. hyperparameter tunning
4. maybe train the network a bit longer

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I made a mistake: I remember that when I was trying to learn Tensorflow, dropout parameter high implies neutralizing too few parameters. So, if that is true or not for tensorflow, now I can understand what is happening as you explicitly explained that dropout high implies too many neurons neutralized. Now it make sense. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Dropout works by probabilistically removing, or “dropping out,” inputs to a layer, which may be input variables in the data sample or activations from a previous layer. It has the effect of simulating a large number of networks with a very different network structure and, in turn, making nodes in the network generally more robust to the inputs.

With dropout (dropout rate less than some small value), the accuracy will gradually increase and loss will gradually decrease first(That is what is happening in your case). 
When you increase dropout beyond a certain threshold, it results in the model not being able to fit properly. Intuitively, a higher dropout rate would result in a higher variance to some of the layers, which also degrades training.

What you should always remember is that Dropout is like all other forms of regularization in that it reduces model capacity. If you reduce the capacity too much, it is sure that you will get bad results.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Are you writing about validation/test performance of training data performance on the snippet: "With dropout (dropout rate less than some small value) ... able to fit properly"? If you are writing about training data performance, and the intuitive reason is that " Intuitively, a higher dropout rate would result in a higher variance to some of the layers, which also degrades training"; then, what do you mean 'higher variance to some of the layers'?

Comment: Thanks  for answer. I had a bad understanding on dropout parameter. I was treating it in the inverse order. Differently to what I thought, dropout parameter high implies too many neutrons neutralized. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Waliston No problem dude. It happens.Happy that you understood the concept well.